# Running two IncrediBuild on same machine?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, incredibuild

Is it possible to use **IncrediBuild** to *simultaneously* build two different clones on the same machine?

Usually the Building (not Rebuilding) of one clone in my system takes 1.5 hours, and most of the time I use two clones for two different bugs/feature. If I can run the build simultaneously on two different clones it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can use IncrediBuild to build simultaneously from two different clones** (this behavior works out-of-the-box and there is nothing special you'll need to do in order to achieve that). 
If you have multiple IncrediBuild Helpers (remote machines that contribute their idle CPU cycles to accelerate the builds running on the machines that initiated the build), each clone will try to use as many Helper machines as it require in order to optimize the build performance.
In your scenario, your available Helpers machines will split their idle resources between the two clones from which you initiate your builds.

We've recently introduced a beta Enterprise version of IncrediBuild that allows you (among other features) to execute two builds in parallel **from the same Initiating machine** (as opposed to two different clones which was always supported in the product), in a scenario in which multiple build are simultaneously executed from the same initiating machine, each such build will potentially use hundreds of cores and gigs of memory you already own across your network to accelerate the build time of both these builds.

Disclaimer, the writer of this answer is part of the IncrediBuild team.